# Delete "Image " word from Fancybox counter in FancyBox gallery

Tags: fancybox, wordpress

I am using FancyBox gallery in a Wordpress theme.

I want to delete:

Image 1 / 1

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use CSS here like

```
#fancybox-title-over{
   display:none;   
}
```

double check the element if it has the id of **fancybox-title-over** using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your help but I need the title. At the moment, I have title and image 1/15... I just want to keep title and delete "image 1/15"... Any idea????